# Toggle all to original state before toggling clicked item

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click an item it expands. When I click another item it also expands but leaves the first one expanded too. I only want one item expanded at any time ie: the one I click on. So I need to basically toggle everything to it's original state and then only expand the one I actually click on. There is a codepen for the example I am using.

```
// external js: masonry.pkgd.js

var $grid = $('.grid').masonry({
  columnWidth: 120,
  itemSelector: '.grid-item'
});

$grid.on( 'click', '.grid-item-content', function( event ) {
  $( event.currentTarget ).parent('.grid-item').toggleClass('is-expanded');
  $grid.masonry();
});
```

See the Pen 
  [Masonry - animate item size](https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/daKBo) by Dave DeSandro ([@desandro](https://codepen.io/desandro))
  on [CodePen](https://codepen.io).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the code like this:

```
var $grid = $('.grid').masonry({
  columnWidth: 120,
  itemSelector: '.grid-item'
});

$grid.on( 'click', '.grid-item-content', function( event ) {
  var parent = $(event.currentTarget).parent('.grid-item'); //Fetch only parent once
  parent.siblings().removeClass('is-expanded'); //Remove class from others
  parent.toggleClass('is-expanded'); //Set class on clicked item
  $grid.masonry();
});
```

This will remove the class from all items (the items parents siblings) before applying it to the item you clicked.